# Render list of words as <span> in a <p> tag in React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering, overflow

I have a list of list of words:

```
document    [ paragraph [w1, w2, w3 ] , [w4, w5, w6] , [w7, ...], ... ]
```

I would like to render them in React Js with double list rendering:

A `<Document>` component render the list of `<Pargraph>` with map(). The `<Pargraph>` render the list of
`<Word>` with map().

My problem is that when i have a too long `<paragraph>`, words goes outside of screen. I tr to insert a `<br>` between words but it doesn't apply. The final resulting rendered html is:

```
<div>  # my Document
  <p> # my paragraph
    <span> <span> <span> ... <br/> <span> <span>
  </p>
  <p>
    ...
  </p>
</div>
```

Problem is that `</br>` doesn't apply, which may be the correct tag to wrap words ?

Here a photo =>
[overflow rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZTCv.png)

---

UPDATE

---

Here the react code to render this :

Document => Paragraph

```
export default class Document extends React.Component<
  DocumentProps,
  DocumentState
> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<DocumentProps>) {
    super(props);
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div id="documentContainer">
        {this.props.document.pargraphs.map((paragraph, index) => {
          return (
            <Paragraph
              key={index}
            ></Paragraph>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Paragraph => Words   [ HERE THE `<br />` ]

```
export default class Paragraph extends React.Component<ParagraphProps, ParagraphState> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<ParagraphProps>) {
    super(props);
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <p className="rowContainer">
        {this.props.text.map((word, index) => {
          console.log(index);
          if (index === 10) return <br />;
          return <Word word={word} key={index}></Word>;
        })}
      </p>
    );
  };
```

Word:

```
export default class Word extends React.Component<WordProps> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<WordProps>) {
    super(props);
  }

  render = () => {
    return <span className="word">{this.props.word}</span>;
  };
}
```

Document has flex css: column-container

Comment: where are you adding the br? I mean in the code.

Comment: That wrapping looks like something that should just be solved using CSS...

Comment: If you're inserting the `<br>` in the `<span>` it won't move to the next line because a `span` is an inline element by default. I can't judge this however because you haven't shown your implementation alongside your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely a `CSS` problem respect to a `React` one.
Have you tried to set a `maxWidth` to your `p` component at `100%`?
Or maybe you can check the `display` properties on the `span` elements, with the inspector in front it can be solved quite fast I think.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the overflowing problem by using white-space: initial in every span inside paragraph and white-space: pre-wrap in paragraph.

Comment: you can also see the live example here https://newsgamer.vercel.app. The newspaper has all the spans.